# __deconstruct not writing session variables

Tags: php, yii, destructor

I have a shopping cart library that contains this function.  From the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php) it states: `PHP 5 introduces a destructor concept similar to that of other object-oriented languages, such as C++. The destructor method will be called as soon as there are no other references to a particular object, or in any order during the shutdown sequence.`

I'm unsure why this isn't being ever called.  Can anyone shed any light on this?

```
public function __deconstruct () {
    Yii::app()->session->add('cart', $this->order);
}
```

Comment: That should be `__destruct`, not `__deconstruct`, so it makes perfect sense that it isn't ever called.

Answer (score 3):

It's `__destruct` not `__deconstruct`

http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php